# save image 1 is whit not black

Tags: python, scipy

I have numpy array of size [8,8,8]

I slice it and for each slice I save it as image using `scipy.misc.imsave`

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 .....

 [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]]
```

however image image is black
see it -->[image]

Comment: The input range used is [0,255]. So 1 is very close to black. Use 255 for white.

Comment: the scale 0 to 1 not 0 to 255

Comment: That is not what imsave expects however. You need it to convert it. You can simply multiply element-wise by 255.

Comment: ok that good answer but if my value between 0 to 1 hot to map it to [0 - 255]

Comment: oh I got it , if value 0.6 just multiply ( 0.6*255) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

White is 255 and Black is 0.

The value you entered (1) is almost black.

Comment: the scale 0 to 1